# mysql query into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with 100 columns.

It happens that I want the query to show only the columns that have "value <> 0"

So the column that has val = 0 should not be displayed.

Can anyone help with this

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Some code and desired results would be nice so we can help you.

Comment: Do you know the column names? Do you have them in a list or somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a query like the following:

`SELECT FLOOR(SUM(IF(column1 IN (0),0,1))/COUNT(*)),FLOOR(SUM(IF(column2 IN (0),0,1))/COUNT(*)),...,FLOOR(SUM(IF(column100 IN (0),0,1))/COUNT(*)) FROM table_name`

This will give you a row with column value = 0 if the column contains `0` and 1 if column contains no `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot adjust the number of columns returned.  That is defined by a projection (your SELECT block) and a projection is evaluated against the table schema.  It is expected that you know the number of columns and the types that you want returned in a projection.

As the previous user had mentioned, you can use a function or case statement to change the value in the column, or alternatively, you can restrict the rows returned with the WHERE clause (if some value or values are <> 0, for example).

The schema of the generated projection table returned must be static though.